# How to resolve SP2-0734 in SQL Plus using CONCAT?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have created a script that generates this error, but it still executes perfectly. What can I do to resolve this error? I have tried some of the common fixes like SET SQLBLANKLINES ON and it didn't work.

The error: SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CONCAT('IN..." - rest of line ignored.

This is the part of the script that generates the error:

```
PROMPT 'ENTER THE PERCENTAGE YOU WISH TO INCREASE THE PRICE BY: '
ACCEPT V_PCT_INCREASE NUMBER
PROMPT
PROMPT 'ENTER THE PRODUCT SEARCH CRITERIA: '
ACCEPT V_PRODUCT_DESC
PROMPT
PROMPT 'YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO UPDATE PRODUCTS WHOSE DESCRIPTION BEGINS WITH &V_PRODUCT_DESC WITH A PERCENTAGE INCREASE OF &V_PCT_INCREASE PERCENT.'
PROMPT
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
SPOOL c:\runscripts\insert_prices.sql;
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)
    VALUES (', P.PRODUCT_ID||', '''||PR.START_DATE||''', '||PR.LIST_PRICE * (1+(&V_PCT_INCREASE/100))||', '||PR.MIN_PRICE * (1+(&V_PCT_INCREASE/100))||', CURRENT_DATE'||');')
FROM TAR_PROD P
JOIN TAR_PRICE PR
ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE UPPER(P.DESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER('&V_PRODUCT_DESC%');
SPOOL OFF;
SET FEEDBACK ON;
SET TERMOUT ON;
PROMPT 'A SCRIPT insert_prices.sql HAS BEEN CREATED AT c:\runscripts\insert_prices.sql'
PROMPT
PROMPT 'THE FOLLOWING PRODUCTS WERE ADDED TO THE INSERT SCRIPT WITH THE ADJUSTED PRICES: '
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID, P.DESCRIPTION, PR.LIST_PRICE, PR.MIN_PRICE,
PR.LIST_PRICE * (1+(&V_PCT_INCREASE/100)) AS "ADJ_LIST_PRICE", 
PR.MIN_PRICE * (1+(&V_PCT_INCREASE/100)) AS "ADJ_MIN_PRICE"
FROM TAR_PROD P
JOIN TAR_PRICE PR
ON P.PRODUCT_ID = PR.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE UPPER(P.DESCRIPTION) LIKE UPPER('&V_PRODUCT_DESC%');
@C:\runscripts\insert_prices.sql
PROMPT 'INSERT SCRIPT IS COMPLETE.'
PROMPT 'SEE BELOW FOR RESULT VALIDATION.'
SELECT *
FROM TAR_TEMP_PRICE;
ROLLBACK;
```

It still works, but I would like the suppress the error.

The insert statements generated by the code above:

```
CONCAT('INSERTINTOTAR_TEMP_PRICE(PRODUCT_ID,START_DATE,LIST_PRICE,MIN_PRICE,END_DATE)VALUES(',P.PRODUCT_ID||','''||PR.START_DATE||''','||PR.LIST_PRICE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100860, '01-JUN-90', 39.2, 31.36, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                             

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100860, '01-JAN-90', 35.84, 28.672, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                           

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100860, '01-JAN-89', 33.6, 26.88, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                             

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100861, '01-JUN-90', 50.4, 40.32, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                             

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100861, '01-JAN-90', 47.04, 37.632, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                           

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100861, '01-JAN-89', 43.68, 34.944, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                           

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100870, '01-JAN-90', 3.136, 2.688, CURRENT_DATE);                                                                                            

INSERT INTO TAR_TEMP_PRICE (PRODUCT_ID, START_DATE, LIST_PRICE, MIN_PRICE, END_DATE)                                                                  
    VALUES (100870, '01-JAN-89', 2.688, 2.128, CURRENT_DATE);
```

For some reason it is adding part of the select statement from the code above.

Here is the output:

```
'ENTER THE PERCENTAGE YOU WISH TO INCREASE THE PRICE BY: '
12

'ENTER THE PRODUCT SEARCH CRITERIA: '
DYN

'YOU HAVE CHOSEN TO UPDATE PRODUCTS WHOSE DESCRIPTION BEGINS WITH DYN WITH A PERCENTAGE INCREASE OF      12 PERCENT.'

'A SCRIPT insert_prices.sql HAS BEEN CREATED AT c:\runscripts\insert_prices.sql'

'THE FOLLOWING PRODUCTS WERE ADDED TO THE INSERT SCRIPT WITH THE ADJUSTED PRICES: '

PRODUCT_ID DESCRIPTION                        LIST_PRICE      MIN_PRICE ADJ_LIST_PRICE  ADJ_MIN_PRICE
---------- ------------------------------ -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
    100860 DynaBlaster 400                        $35.00         $28.00         $39.20         $31.36
    100860 DynaBlaster 400                        $32.00         $25.60         $35.84         $28.67
    100860 DynaBlaster 400                        $30.00         $24.00         $33.60         $26.88
    100861 Dynablaster 600                        $45.00         $36.00         $50.40         $40.32
    100861 Dynablaster 600                        $42.00         $33.60         $47.04         $37.63
    100861 Dynablaster 600                        $39.00         $31.20         $43.68         $34.94
    100870 Dynablaster xl60                        $2.80          $2.40          $3.14          $2.69
    100870 Dynablaster xl60                        $2.40          $1.90          $2.69          $2.13

8 rows selected.

SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "CONCAT('IN..." - rest of line ignored.
```

Comment: Perhaps your script have some control characters. You run it from unix/windows?

Comment: I'm running it on Windows 8 in SQLPlus.

Comment: You actually form a `INSERT` in your `SELECT` , but your output here shows as columns??

Comment: That output was for validation. I added the rest of the script to show what happens after the spooling.

Comment: can you show the first few lines of the file "insert_prices.sql" ??  I think maybe the quotes may be messing up the SQL string ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your SQL*Plus prompts. (`SET HEAD OFF`)

```
SET TERMOUT OFF;
SET VERIFY OFF;
SET SQLBLANKLINES ON;
SET HEAD OFF /* This turns of the headers in result */
SET FEEDBACK OFF /* Turns off the result feedback */
```

Issue is the result column of your `SELECT` had the default name starting with `CONCAT(..` as alias.

So it is like..

```
CONCAT('INSERTINTOTAR_TEMP_PRICE(PRODUCT_ID,START_DATE,LIST_PRICE,MIN_PRICE,END_DATE)VALUES(',P.PRODUCT_ID||','''||PR.START_DATE||''','||PR.LIST_PRICE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And as you execute your `INSERT` script, even tht gets executed along with your other inserts. So, we have to turn off the headers.

Comment: I fixed it just before reading your comment. I set pagesize to 0 and it worked. Your solution should work as well so I will mark it as the answer. Thanks!